# Spring boot app connecting to 2 H2 databases

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, db2, h2

In production, my app will need to talk to two different relational databases from different vendors (for example DB2 and MySQL or Oracle)
For development, I intend to use H2 databases to represent the two used in production.

For example TableA is what will be in DB2 and TableB will be in Oracle.

How to configure H2 this way so it knows that JPA/Hibernate generates TableA for DB2 AND TableB for Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your application into two apps. Then use `restTemplate` to get data from one app to another.

So in `dev` mode use `h2` in each app.